# C# Format foreach loop as Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am getting started with C# and got the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class PrefixMapSum : Dictionary<String, int> {

    public bool insert(String key, int value) {
        return base.TryAdd(key, value);
    } 

    public int sum(String prefix) {
        int sum = 0;

        foreach (String key in base.Keys) {
            if (key.StartsWith(prefix)) {
                sum = sum + base[key];
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Now I'd love to shorten the following part of the code with lambda-expressions:

```
        foreach (String key in base.Keys) {
            if (key.StartsWith(prefix)) {
                sum = sum + base[key];
            }
        }
```

I tried with:

```
new List<String>(base.Keys).ForEach(key => key.StartsWith(prefix) ? sum = sum + base[key] : sum = sum);
```

Yet i am running into this error: [CS0201](https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0201)

I am coming from Java and I can't quite figure out why it does not work. Can anyone explain what I should do differently (and why)?

Comment: You'd get a similar error in Java. You tried to use the ternary operator as if it were an `if` block. Assignments are expressions, so this call will return a value BUT `ForEach` expects statements that do something, not expressions

Comment: There are better ways to filter and aggregate values in Java, using streams for example. The syntax itself is quite similar to LINQ's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will only work when there is at least one element after the filtering.

```
base.Keys
   .Where(key=> key.StartsWith(prefix))
   .Sum(base[key])
```

If there can be none(The method cannot sum), you can use this `DefaultIfEmpty`so you will have the sum as 0.

```
base.Keys
   .Where(key=> key.StartsWith(prefix))
   .Select(key=> base[key])
   .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
   .Sum()
```

For performance reasons you would probably like to avoid using the indexer, and iterate the dictionary yourself.

```
var defaultZero = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(string.Empty, 0);
var sum = this
          .Where(pair => pair.Key.StartsWith(prefix))
          .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultZero)
          .Sum(pair => pair.Value);
```

If you need to handle the case where there is no element separately you can do something like

```
var elements =this
   .Where(pair => pair.Key.StartsWith(prefix))
   .Select(x=>x.Value);
if(!elements.Any()){
    // your logic here
}else{
    sum= elements.Sum();
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, the example above tells me CS0103 (key is not known for the select-part)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it with `System.Linq`, use [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) method to filter the keys, then get [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32__) of values for filtered keys by passing `Func<string, int>` selector

```cs
public int sum(string prefix)
{
    return base.Keys.Where(key => key.StartsWith(prefix)).Sum(key => base[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put it as a simple *Linq* query:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int sum = this
  .Where(pair => pair.Key.StartsWith(prefix))
  .Sum(pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: `base.Where` didn't work. You should work on `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq:

```
            var sum = base.Keys.Where(key => key.StartsWith(prefix))
                          .Sum(key => base[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, avoid the indexer (ie: calls to `base[key]`) if you can. Here you can directly work on the `KeyValuePair` enumeration:

```
public int Sum(string prefix) => this.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith(prefix)).Sum(kvp => kvp.Value);
```